# How to get and put values of these specific fields using class in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the values from 2 input tags and then multiply them and put the result in the third input tag.

I successfully got value from input tags but the problem is that i cant get specific values. I need to use class as my main purpose is to get cart items using a foreach loop. I tried using $(this) keyword but failed.

HTML:

```
price :<input type="text" class="inp" value=45>
quantity: <input type="text" class="inp-text" placeholder="enter a number" >
total:<input type="text" class="result" placeholder="result"><br><br>

price :<input type="text" class="inp" value=10>
quantity: <input type="text" class="inp-text" placeholder="enter a number" >
total:<input type="text" class="result" placeholder="result"><br><br>

price :<input type="text" class="inp" value=29>
quantity: <input type="text" class="inp-text" placeholder="enter a number" >
total:<input type="text" class="result" placeholder="result"><br><br>
```

Jquery

```
$(".inp-text").keyup(function() {
    console.log("key action");
    var key1 = $(this).val();
    // I want the value of this specific input class .inp and .inp-text
    $(".inp").attr("value", function() {
        var key2 = $(this).val();
        console.log(key1);
        console.log(key2);
        // multiply those values and then display it in result class
        var ress = key1 * key2;
        $(".result").val(ress);
    });
});
```

I want to display the multiplication of the price and quantity in the result field.
eg. on changing the input of the 2nd row to 5 it should generate 50 in result column.

10 * 5 = 50

Comment: Add a custom attribute to each inp-text fields using jquery (dynamically if you wish). This custom attribute is to identify which inp belongs to which inp-text, the value of this attribute will be $('.inp').val(). You can use this to identify inp-text for each field.

Comment: No need for that. Each already has an index relative to others with the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the index of the element relative to others with the same class (use the selector in the index function).

```
var index = $(this).index(".inp-text");
```

The code in this fiddle will do the trick:

```
$(".inp-text").keyup(function() {
    console.log("key action");
    var index = $(this).index(".inp-text");
    var key1 = $(this).val();
    // I want the value of this specific input class .inp and .inp-text
    $(".inp:eq("+index+")").attr("value", function() {
        var key2 = $(this).val();
        console.log(key1);
        console.log(key2);
        // multiply those values and then display it in result class
        var ress = key1 * key2;
        $(".result:eq("+index+")").val(ress);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/52Lvmtdr/